# AngularJS - Opening links in a new window using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

First off, I'm not sure if the title I came up accurately describes what I'm trying to do.

I have a table of tasks, with an assign action for each. Basically, in normal cases, the user would click the link, in which a call would be made to assign them to the task and then redirect them to the task details page. That can be done with a simple `ng-click` to call the assign function, and then using the `$location.path()` function for the redirect on success. Doing it this way, there is no need for the `href` attribute.

But, this also takes away the ability to open the link in a new tab by "middle clicking" or "ctrl + clicking" because there's no `href` value. For example, some users would typically assign themselves to multiple tasks at a time. On a typical site, it would just be a regular link that does some processing, finishes, and then loads the page they were intending to go to. So they could get away with opening multiple tabs, because all of them would process the request and then return the page as the response.

So I've added an `ng-href` attribute since I have an ID in there, and it kind of works. Middle clicking (or ctrl + clicking) will still call the `ng-click` function, and the `ng-href` will let the new tab open. But now the issue I have is that since the assign function call is async, sometimes the tab will load up not showing that they're assigned, since the page loaded before the assignment was processed.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to make this more reliable and accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just use

```
        $window.open(LOCATION);
```

instead of $location.path() ?

Comment: I'll look into it. But the idea was that if they click it normally, then they would be directed to the page like a normal link. However, if they open a new tab with it, it would do all the same processing, but open the page as a new tab.